# How to deal with exception handling in python?

Tags: python

Lets say I have a variable city which accepts any city name , like

```
city='London'
```

or

```
city='New York'
```

It accepts only city name but if user mistakenly specifies city name some different like

```
city='Londo'
```

How does should I deal with it means I want to use try catch in it , But How ?

Comment: This question does not seem to be about data science. Also, a simple google search will tell you sites that show how to implement a try-except block in Python or simply perform user input validation.

Answer (score 0):

In an interactive program,

```
If no matching city name found
then shows the input value again and ask the user to enter another value
```

In data preparation,

```
select unmatching city names 
and find patterns of mistakes
use regular expression accordingly to replace the mismatching city names with the right ones
for example, new_df = df.replace(to_replace ='Londo.*', value = 'London', regex = True)
```

That is how I would do.